# Finding recurrence for Domino Tiling

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am trying to solve [this](http://www.spoj.com/problems/GNY07H/) problem on spoj.By using tutorial in this    [Link](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/UVa_10918) I am able to figure out this recurrence.

```
*****    AA***    AA***    AA***    A****
***** =  AA***  + A****  + AA***  + A****
*****    AA***    A****    A****    AA***
*****    AA***    AA***    A****    AA***

f(n)  =  f(n-2) + h(n-1) + g(n-1) + g(n-1).
```

But I can't understand how to solve the recurrence for h(n-1) and g(n-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a term in the `f` recurrence.

```
*****   A****    AA***    AA***    AA***    A****
*****   A****    BB***    B****    BB***    A****
*****   B****    CC***    B****    C****    BB***
*****   B****    DD***    CC***    C****    CC***
f(n)  = f(n-1) + f(n-2) + h(n-1) + g(n-1) + g(n-1)
```

Here are the other recurrences. The idea is to figure out all possible domino placements for the leftmost column with unfilled squares.

```
*****   A****    AA***
*****   A****    BB***
 ****    ****     ****
 ****    ****     ****
g(n)  = f(n-1) + g(n-1)

 ****    ****     ****
*****   A****    AA***
*****   A****    BB***
 ****    ****     ****
h(n)  = f(n-1) + k(n-1)

*****   AA***
 ****    ****
 ****    ****
*****   BB***
k(n)  = h(n-1)
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how you have taken g(n) in above figure.

Comment: @pallesaikrishna The sum implicitly is over all ways to cover the two unfilled squares in the leftmost column. Either you can have one vertical domino, which reduces to the state that you called `f`, or you can have two horizontal dominoes, which leaves a `g` configuration of width one less.

Answer (score 2):

You need recurrence relations for *all 16 possible* profiles of the side:

```
##
##
##
##

#.
##
##
##

##
#.
##
##

...

##
#.
#.
#.

#.
#.
#.
#.
```

Here `#` means a cell occupied by a domino, and `.` an empty cell.

You can denote them by `f(n,0)` to `f(n,15)` and then the recursive relations will be rather easy to write. You can even automatically enumerate these profiles and generate the relations. Or you can manually decrease the number of profiles by a factor of 2 by noticing the symmetry (like you have noticed it for your two `g`'s), and manually write the equations.